# Find the gradient of $f(x,y,x)$ given its maximum value at a point $P_0$ in the direction $(1,1,-1)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I am asked to solve the following problem:

The directional derivative of the function $f(x,y,z)$ has maximum value of $2\sqrt{3}$ at the point $P_0$ in the direction $(1,1,-1)$. What is the gradient of $f$ at the point? What is the derivative of $f(x,y,z)$ on the direction $(1,1,0)$?

My solution:

Let's say the gradient is $(a,b,c)$ and given that the unit vector for the direction $(1,1,-1)$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \left( 1,1,-1 \right)$

$$
2 \sqrt{3} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} (a,b,c) \cdot (1,1,-1)\\
6 = (a,b,c) \cdot (1,1,-1)\\
a+b-c = 6
$$

We also know that he maximum value for the directional derivative occurs on the direction of the gradient:

$$
(a,b,c) = k (1,1,-1)\\
a = k\\
b = k\\
c = -k
$$

Substituting the equations found, we have that $k=2$ and

$$(a,b,c) = (2,2,-2)$$

For the second question, the directional derivative is

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (2,2,-2) \cdot (1,1,0) = 2 \sqrt{2}
$$

Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Thank you.